# How to call scanf_s in assembly to input a char?

Tags: visual-c++, assembly

this is part of code ("call scanf_s"  to input a int)
but how to  call scanf_s to input a char?

```
char format[]="%d"; //format string for the scanf function 
int first;
_asm{ 

      lea eax,first
      push eax 
      lea eax,format; 读取第一个number 
      push eax 
      call scanf_s
      add esp,8

        mov eax,dword ptr [first]
        push eax
        lea eax,format
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp,8

}
```

Comment: All the format specifiers are listed in [the documentation for `scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf_s` needs an additional parameter for characters. From the [Microsoft manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w40768et.aspx):

> scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all
>   input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are
>   enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an
>   additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer
>   or variable.

The C form of this function looks like `scanf_s ("%c",&char,1);`. Push the arguments from right to left in assembly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
    char scanf_fmt[] = "%c";
    char printf_fmt[] = "%c\n";
    char character;

    _asm
    {
        push 1                  // Buffer size, you can also write `push size character`
        lea eax, character
        push eax                // Pointer to character
        lea eax, scanf_fmt
        push eax                // Pointer to format string
        call scanf_s
        add esp, 12             // Clean up three pushes

        movzx eax, byte ptr [character] // MOVZX: Load one unsigned byte into a 32-bit-register
        push eax                // Character as value
        lea eax, printf_fmt
        push eax                // Pointer to format string
        call printf
        add esp,8               // Clean up two pushes
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After read your code,I know my fault is I don't notice"scanf_s needs an additional parameter for characters".This question have tormented me for two days. Much obliged！ ^_^